# Maximum simulated likelihood estimation in R - binary logit example

Tags: r, maximum-likelihood, numerical-integration

Very often the likelihood function involves an integral which does not have a closed-form solution (e.g., random coefficients, latent variables). In these cases, we can employ monte-carlo simulation to approximate the integral: For example, $\int t(x, e) f(e) de$ has no closed-form solution.

1. Take a random draw from the error distribution $e_1$.
2. Plug $e_1$ into the $t(x, e)$ and evaluate. -> $t_1$.
3. Repeat 1. and 2. $R$ times.
4. The average $1/R \sum_{r=1}^{R}t_r$ approximates the integral.

I try to explore this algorithm in the most simple case, a binary logistic regression model. I want to compare the maximum simulated likelihood estimates to the closed-form solution. Below, the problem is illustrated. For a more complete example with the underlying formulas and reasoning see https://github.com/dheimgartner/DCM/blob/main/vignettes/full-simulation-binary.pdf

### Simulate some data for illustration

```r
simulate_binary <- function(beta = c(ASC = 0, beta1 = 1, beta2 = 2), 
                            n = 1000, seed = 0) {
  set.seed(seed)
  simulated_data <- list()

  simulated_data$beta <- beta

  x1 <- rnorm(n) # does not need to be normal!
  x2 <- rnorm(n)

  latent <- beta["ASC"] + beta["beta1"] * x1 + beta["beta2"] * x2
  choice <- as.numeric(latent + rlogis(n) > 0)

  simulated_data$data <- data.frame(x1, x2, choice)

  return(simulated_data)
}

sim_dat <- simulate_binary(n = 10e3)
beta <- sim_dat$beta
dat <- sim_dat$data

beta
head(dat)
```

### Using R's `stats::glm`

```r
fit <- glm(choice ~ x1 + x2, data = dat, 
           family = binomial(link = "logit"))
summary(fit)
```

### Closed-form own implementation

```r
loglik <- function(param) {
  latent <- param["ASC"] + param["beta1"] * dat$x1 + 
                       param["beta2"] * dat$x2
  exp <- exp(latent)
  P_1n <- exp / (1 + exp)
  P_0n <- 1 - P_1n

  y_1n <- dat$choice
  y_0n <- 1 - y_1n

  ll <- sum(y_1n * log(P_1n) + y_0n * log(P_0n))
  cat(ll, "\n")
  ll
}

p <- function(v) {
  v <- setNames(v, c("ASC", "beta1", "beta2"))
  v
}

param <- p(c(1, 1, 1))
m <- maxLik::maxLik(loglik, start = param, method = "BFGS")
summary(m)
```

### Maximum simulated likelihood

```r
n_draws <- 1000
n_rows <- nrow(dat)
draws_matrix <- matrix(rlogis(n_draws * n_rows), nrow = n_rows, 
                       ncol = n_draws)

loglik <- function(param, epsilon = 1e-10) {
  # 10000 x 1
  latent <- param["ASC"] + param["beta1"] * dat$x1 + 
                       param["beta2"] * dat$x2

  # 10000 x n_draws
  indicator_ <- latent + draws_matrix

  indicator <- (indicator_ > 0)
  P_1n <- apply(indicator, 1, mean)
  P_1n <- pmax(pmin(P_1n, 1 - epsilon), epsilon)
  P_0n <- 1 - P_1n

  y_1n <- dat$choice
  y_0n <- 1 - y_1n
  
  ll <- sum(y_1n * log(P_1n) + y_0n * log(P_0n))
  cat(ll, "\n")
  ll
}
```

Clearly, our `loglik` function makes sense: Evaluated at the true parameters, we get the highest likelihood (which almost matches the non-simulated likelihood from the chapter before):

```r
loglik(p(c(0, 0, 0)))
loglik(p(c(1, 1, 1)))
loglik(p(c(0, 1, 2)))
```

**Remark:** The line `P_1n <- pmax(pmin(P_1n, 1 - epsilon), epsilon)` is needed because the simulated integral (depending on the parameter values passed to it) can yield `P_1n = 0` which results in `-Inf` when taking the log. Similarly, `P_1n = 1` would yield `P_0n = 0` and thus the same problem. Therefore we add (or subtract) a very small value `epsilon` to 0 (from 1).

### Problem

The above maximum simulated likelihood estimator does not converge (or at least is very sensitive to starting values and does not seem to update the parameters reasonably in each itteration). Is it because the approximation with random draws (or `pmax`) introduces some non-smoothness into the loglikelihood function? Are there other strategies to write the simulated loglikelihood function (avoiding the problem of taking log of 0)? However, I've also tried to maximize the likelihood (without taking logs) and the convergence issues are still present...

### Update

Plotting the surface of the simulated loglikelihood clearly shows the expected wiggles (the surface is not smooth) which is a problem for the numerical optimization. How does one deal with it?

[image: wiggly-loglik]